# Разбить файл на части по указанному кол-ву строк С++

Tags: c++

помогите пожалуйста с решением, нужно
составить программу, которая способна разбить какой-либо файл на части по указанному количеству строк и записать эти части каждую в отдельный файл. Имя входного файла вводит пользователь. Программа также должна уметь составлять один главный файл из различных частей, находящихся в различных файлах.
Не совсем понимаю как разбить файл на части по кол-ву строк.

Comment: Читаете построчно, увеличиваете счетчик, записываете строки. Счетчик дошел до нужного значения - часть завершена. Переходим к новому файлу...

Comment: Не могу разобраться в синтаксисе, можно пример, пожалуйста?

Comment: Ну что-то же вы умеете? Открыть файл, прочесть из него строку? Записать? Ваш первый вопрос - *Не совсем понимаю как разбить файл на части по кол-ву строк*. Сейчас вы уже хотите помощи в синтаксисе. Синтаксисе чего? Давайте не будем играть в игру *"ой, дайте воды напиться, а то так есть хочется, что даже переночевать негде..."* :)

Comment: Не умею работать с файлами - поэтому и попросил помощи на этом сайте. Не нашёл достаточной информации с примерами именно по этому вопросу

Comment: Ну не будут тут писать готовый код на простейшее задание, не будут. http://cppstudio.com/post/446/  https://purecodecpp.com/archives/2751  https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0+%D1%81+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%A1%2B%2B

Comment: Хорошо, значит буду лучше вчитываться в документацию, вы дали мне стимул :)